# Active by default profile from parent POM does not activate profiles with same id in sub modules

Tags: java, maven

**Introduction**

I have a multi module maven project. The structure and further details are described below.

```
pom.xml
module-a
 - src/main/resources/demo.properties
module-b
 - pom.xml
 - module-b1
    - pom.xml
    - src/main/resources/demo.properties
 - module-b2
    - pom.xml
    - src/main/resources/demo.properties
    - src/templates/active-by-default/
    - src/templates/other-profile/
```

I am trying to achieve two things:

- (1) copy the content from the directory `src/templates/<some-folder-name>` based on a specific profile to the `target` folder of `module-b2`
- (2) overriding properties for resource filtering.

Please note, that the full code example is available via [GitHub](https://github.com/rzo1/maven-stackoverflow).

**Maven Setup**

In this context, I have defined the `<profiles>` section in the root `pom.xml` as follows:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>active-by-default-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <some.props>some-props-from-active-by-default</some.props>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>other-profile</id>
        <properties>
            <some.props>some-props-from-other-profile</some.props>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In `module-b1` I am overriding the given profile id's and override the property `some.props` from the parent `pom.xml`:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>active-by-default-profile</id>
        <properties>
            <some.props>overridden-by-default-in-submodule-b1</some.props>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>other-profile</id>
        <properties>
            <some.props>some-other-props-overridden-in-submodule-b1</some.props>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In `module-b2` (there I want to copy files with the maven ant plugin in version 3.0.0) it looks like:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>active-by-default-profile</id>
        <properties>
            <copy.source>${project.basedir}/src/templates/active-by-default/</copy.source>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>other-profile</id>
        <properties>
            <copy.source>${project.basedir}/src/templates/other-profile/</copy.source>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Additional Output**

Output of `mvn help:active-profiles`:

```
Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-b:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-b1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-b2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

Output of `mvn help:active-profiles -Pactive-by-default-profile`:

```
Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-b:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-b1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:module-b1:1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)



Active Profiles for Project 'org.example:module-b2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:module-b2:1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 - active-by-default-profile (source: org.example:issue-with-ant-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

**Problem Statement**

Executing `mvn clean install` results in a build failure as the related `copy.source` property cannot be resolved during the ant plugin execution. In addition, the property `some.props` is not overridden.

If I am going to specifiy the profile explicitly via `mvn clean install -Pactive-by-default-profile` everything works as expected.

If it matters: I am using Maven in version 3.6.3 on an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system.

**Question**

- Why is the `activeByDefault` activiation not propagated down to the related sub modules? (in the same way it is done via `-P`?
- What is the rational behind it? Has it something to do with the limitations of POM inheritance?
- Do I need to add additional `<activation>` blocks in every sub-module in which I intend to have an active by default profile? Are there other "workarounds" for this?